# Is it possible to mimic this java enum code in c#

Tags: c#, java, enums

Is it possible to copy this functionality of offering an abstract method in an enum that inner enum constants must override and provide functionality to?

```
public enum Logic {
    PAY_DAY {
        @Override
        public void acceptPlayer(Player player) {
            // Perform logic
        }
    },
    COLLECT_CASH {
        @Override
        public void acceptPlayer(Player player) {
            // Perform logic
        }
    }
    ,
    ETC_ETC {
        @Override
        public void acceptPlayer(Player player) {
            // Perform logic
        }
    };

    public abstract void acceptPlayer(Player player);
}
```

**If it can't::**
Could you provide a way which I can implement lots of specific logic in a similar manner?

Edit :: I know that enums in C# are not really 'objects' like they are in Java, but I wish to perform similar logic.

Edit :: To clarify, I do not want to provide concrete classes for each specific bit of logic. IE, creating an interface acceptPlayer and creating many new classes is not appropiate

Comment: This is **not** possible in C# enums - there is no support for such a feature.

Comment: And instead of explaining what you **don't** want, tell us what you **do** to achieve.

Comment: You could create an `Action` factory that you pass it a value and it gives you back a related `Action` to execute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one option - not using enums, but something similar-ish...

```
public abstract class Logic
{
    public static readonly Logic PayDay = new PayDayImpl();
    public static readonly Logic CollectCash = new CollectCashImpl();
    public static readonly Logic EtcEtc = new EtcEtcImpl();

    // Prevent other classes from subclassing
    private Logic() {}

    public abstract void AcceptPlayer(Player player);

    private class PayDayImpl : Logic
    {
        public override void AcceptPlayer(Player player)
        {
            // Perform logic
        }
    }

    private class CollectCashImpl : Logic
    {
        public override void AcceptPlayer(Player player)
        {
            // Perform logic
        }
    }

    private class EtcEtcImpl : Logic
    {
        public override void AcceptPlayer(Player player)
        {
            // Perform logic
        }
    }
}
```

You *say* that you don't want to provide a concrete class for each bit of logic - but that's basically what you'd be doing in Java anyway, it's just that the class would be slightly hidden from you.

Here's an alternative approach using delegates for the varying behaviour:

```
public sealed class Logic
{
    public static readonly Logic PayDay = new Logic(PayDayAccept);
    public static readonly Logic CollectCash = new Logic(CollectCashAccept);
    public static readonly Logic EtcEtc = new Logic(player => {
        // An alternative using lambdas...
    });

    private readonly Action<Player> accept;

    private Logic(Action<Player> accept)
    {
        this.accept = accept;
    }

    public void AcceptPlayer(Player player)
    {
        accept(player);
    }

    private static void PayDayAccept(Player player)
    {
        // Logic here
    }

    private static void CollectCashAccept(Player player)
    {
        // Logic here
    }
}
```

In both cases, you still get a fixed set of values - but you won't be able to switch on them. You could potentially have a separate "real" enum, but that would be a bit messy.

Comment: I did see this as an option, but it's still providing concrete classes really. Can something be done with delegates perhaps?

Comment: Hey I feel pretty cool, I thought of the same solution as Jon Skeet (and I hadn't even seen his first). I am DA MAN.

Comment: @AlanFoster: The enum solution in Java is "still providing concrete classes really" - so why is it okay for you in Java but not in C#? Note that I've provided two bits of code here - the second *does* use delegates.

Comment: @JonSkeet ah, the second looks much cleaner. Any reason why you wouldn't use a struct here and be closer to enums?

Comment: @nawfal: For one thing, because anyone could then use `new Logic()`. But otherwise, it would work.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh yes, missed it. Love classes more for that feature :) But then you could do `EnumType g = new EnumType();` too.. :(

Comment: @nawfal: Which `EnumType` type are you talking about? (My classes are sealed and have private constructors.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant a normal `enum`. Something like `enum Relation { Sister, Brother, Cousin }`. Then one could do `Relation r = new Relation();` just like any other struct. And thats sad. I was saying the ability to instantiate a struct with default constructor *may* not be a good reason to choose class over struct for this kind of thing. But due to the nature of VS intellisense, hardly anyone would think of doing `new Relation()` :)

Comment: @nawfal: Right, yes. Enums in C# aren't really "safe" in that you can just cast from *any* value of the underlying type to the enum. They're named numbers rather than a set of valid values.

Comment: "named numbers", i like that usage, perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use interfaces and a class hierarchy, you could use delegates, something like :

```
public class Player{}

public static class Logic
{
    public static readonly Action<Player> PAY_DAY = p => Console.WriteLine( "Pay day : " + p.ToString());

    public static readonly Action<Player> COLLECT_CASH = p=> Console.WriteLine(p.ToString ());

    public static void AcceptPlayer( this Action<Player> PlayerAction, Player ActingPlayer )
    {
        PlayerAction(ActingPlayer);
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var player = new Player();

        Logic.PAY_DAY.AcceptPlayer( player );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what the name of this is? How is it that player.AcceptPlayer is now a valid method for player, when you declared it in a different class?

Comment: It's an extension method (actually I have edited it so that it works more like your question) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx. The this keyword on the first argument means that any instance of the Action<Player> type will have the AcceptPlayer method associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

I like the advantages of Java enums and wanted to try to simulate them.  I have looked at many posts here and could not find a simple way to do this so I came up with the following.  I am not a professional so please forgive me for any stupid mistakes. 
This, I beleive, provides almost all of the functionality to a Java enum (I did not write a clone method).

Also, I apologize for the length of this post.

This is the abstract class:

```
#region + Using Directives
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using TestEnum;

#endregion

namespace TestEnum
{
    public abstract class ACsEnum<T, U, V> :
        IComparable<ACsEnum<T, U, V>>
        where T : ACsEnum<T, U, V>
    {
        static ACsEnum()
        {
            // the static constructor causes
            // early creation of the object
            Count = 0;
        }

        // constructor
        protected ACsEnum(Enum m, V v)
        {
            Enum = m;
            Value = v;
            Ordinal = Count++;
        }

    #region Admin Private fields

        // the list of members
        protected static readonly List<T> members = new List<T>();

    #endregion

    #region Admin Public Properties

        // the enum associated with this class
        public Enum Enum { get; }

        // number of members
        public static int Count { get; private set; }

        // ordinal number of this member (zero based)
        public int Ordinal { get; }

        // a name of this member
        public string Name => ToString();

        // the value attached to the enum
        public U Amount => (U) (IConvertible) Enum;

        // the value of this member - this value is
        // returned from the implicit conversion
        public V Value { get; }

    #endregion

    #region Admin Operator

        public static implicit operator V (ACsEnum<T, U, V> m)
        {
            return m.Value;
        }

    #endregion

    #region Admin Functions

        // compare
        public int CompareTo(ACsEnum<T, U, V> other)
        {
            if (other.GetType() != typeof(T)) { return -1; }

            return Ordinal.CompareTo(other.Ordinal);
        }

        // determine if the name provided is a member
        public static bool IsMember(string name, bool caseSensitive)
        {
            return Find(name, caseSensitive) != null;
        }

        // finds and returns a member
        public static T Find (string name, bool caseSensitive = false)
        {
            if (caseSensitive)
            {
                return members.Find(s => s.ToString().Equals(name));
            }
            else
            {
                return members.Find(s => s.ToString().ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower()));
            }
        }

        // allow enumeration over the members
        public static IEnumerable Members()
        {
            foreach (T m in members)
            {
                yield return m;
            }
        }

        // get the members as an array
        public static T[] Values()
        {
            return members.ToArray();
        }

        // same as Find but throws an exception 
        public static T ValueOf(string name)
        {
            T m = Find(name, true);

            if (m != null) return m;

            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException();
        }

    #endregion

    #region Admin Overrides

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj != null && obj.GetType() != typeof(T)) return false;

            return ((T) obj).Ordinal == Ordinal ;
        }

    #endregion
    }
}
```

This is an extension method to help with enum's:

```
namespace TestEnum
{
    // special enum extension that gets the value of an enum
    // 
    public static class EnumEx
    {
        public static dynamic Value(this Enum e)
        {
            switch (e.GetTypeCode())
            {
            case TypeCode.Byte:
                {
                    return (byte) (IConvertible) e;
                }
            case TypeCode.Int16:
                {
                    return (short) (IConvertible) e;
                }
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                {
                    return (int) (IConvertible) e;
                }
            case TypeCode.Int64:
                {
                    return (long) (IConvertible) e;
                }
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
                {
                    return (ushort) (IConvertible) e;
                }
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
                {
                    return (uint) (IConvertible) e;
                }
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                {
                    return (ulong) (IConvertible) e;
                }
            case TypeCode.SByte:
                {
                    return (sbyte) (IConvertible) e;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the actual "enum" class:

```
namespace TestEnum
{
    public class Planet : ACsEnum<Planet, byte, double>
    {
    #region Base enum

        // this holds the position from the sun
        public enum planet : byte
        {
            MERCURY = 1,
            VENUS   = 2,
            EARTH   = 3,
            MARS    = 4,
            JUPITER = 5,
            SATURN  = 6,
            URANUS  = 7,
            NEPTUNE = 8,
            PLUTO   = 9
        }

    #endregion

    #region ctror

        // planet enum, mass, radius, orbital period (earth days)
        private Planet(   planet p, double m, double r, double v) : base(p, v)
        {
            Mass = m;
            Radius = r;

            members.Add(this);
        }

    #endregion

    #region enum specific Properties

        public double Mass { get;  }
        public double Radius { get;  }

    #endregion

    #region enum specific Functions

        public static double G = 6.67300E-11;

        public double SurfaceGravity()
        {
            return (G * Mass) / (Radius * Radius);
        }

        public double SurfaceWeight(double otherMass)
        {
            return otherMass * SurfaceGravity();
        }

    #endregion

    #region Overrides

        public override string ToString() => Enum.ToString();

    #endregion

    #region Members

        //                                                          enum      mass            radius       "year"
        public static readonly Planet MERCURY   = new Planet(planet.MERCURY, 3.303e+23     , 2.4397e6   ,     88.0);
        public static readonly Planet VENUS     = new Planet(planet.VENUS  , 4.869e+24     , 6.0518e6   ,    224.7);
        public static readonly Planet EARTH     = new Planet(planet.EARTH  , 5.976e+24     , 6.37814e6  ,    365.2);
        public static readonly Planet MARS      = new Planet(planet.MARS   , 6.421e+23     , 3.3972e6   ,    687.0);
        public static readonly Planet JUPITER   = new Planet(planet.JUPITER, 1.9e+27       , 7.1492e7   ,   4331.0);
        public static readonly Planet SATURN    = new Planet(planet.SATURN , 5.688e+26     , 6.0268e7   ,  10747.0);
        public static readonly Planet URANUS    = new Planet(planet.NEPTUNE, 8.686e+25     , 2.5559e7   ,  30589.0);
        public static readonly Planet NEPTUNE   = new Planet(planet.URANUS , 1.024e+26     , 2.4746e7   ,  59800.0);
        public static readonly Planet PLUTO     = new Planet(planet.PLUTO  , 11.30900e+22  , 1.187e6    ,  90560.0);

    #endregion

    }
}
```

Lastly, here is the usage example:

```
using System;
using static TestEnum.Planet;

namespace TestEnum
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();

            p.EnumTest();

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nWaiting ...:  ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private void EnumTest()
        {

            // test:
            // each admin property: count, ordinal, value, name
            // each unique property: APlanet, Mass, Radius, G
            // implicit operator
            // admin functions: 
            // admin overrides:
            // unique properties
            // unique functions

            Console.WriteLine("\nadmin properties\n");
            Console.WriteLine("count     | " + Planet.Count + "  (== 9)");
            Console.WriteLine("ordinal   | " + MERCURY.Ordinal + "  (== 0)");
            Console.WriteLine("name      | " + MERCURY.Name + " (== MERCURY)");
            Console.WriteLine("value     | " + MERCURY.Value + " (== 88 Mercury year)");

            double x = EARTH;

            Console.WriteLine("\nadmin Operator\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Year      | " + x + "  (== 365.2 year)");

            Console.WriteLine("\nadmin functions\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Compare to| " + MERCURY.CompareTo(EARTH) + "  (== -1)");
            Console.WriteLine("IsMember  | " + Planet.IsMember("EARTH", true) + "  (== true)");
            Console.WriteLine("Find      | " + Planet.Find("EARTH", true).Name + "  (== EARTH)");
            Console.WriteLine("ValueOf   | " + Planet.ValueOf("EARTH").Name + "  (== EARTH)");
            Console.WriteLine("Equals    | " + EARTH.Equals(MERCURY) + " (== false => EARTH != MERCURY)");

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nunique admin\n");
            Console.WriteLine("G         | " + Planet.G);

            Console.WriteLine("\nunique properties\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Enum      | " + MERCURY.Enum);
            Console.WriteLine("Mass      | " + MERCURY.Mass);
            Console.WriteLine("Radius    | " + MERCURY.Radius);
            Console.WriteLine("amount    | " + MERCURY.Amount + "  (== 1 MERCURY first planet)");

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nunique functions");

            // typical Java enum usage example

            double earthWeight = 175; // lbs

            double mass = earthWeight / EARTH.SurfaceGravity();

            Console.WriteLine("\ncalc weight via foreach\n");

            foreach (Planet p in Planet.Members())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your weight on {0} is {1:F5}",
                    p.Name, p.SurfaceWeight(mass));
            }

            // end, typical Java enum usage example

            // test Values

            Planet[] planets = Planet.Values();

            Console.WriteLine("\ncalc weight  via array\n");

            foreach (Planet p in planets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your weight on {0} is {1:F5}",
                    p.Name, p.SurfaceWeight(mass));
            }

            // test switch
            Planet planet = PLUTO;

            Console.WriteLine("\nuse switch - looking for PLUTO\n");

            switch (planet.Enum)
            {
            case Planet.planet.EARTH:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("found EARTH\n");
                    break;
                }
            case Planet.planet.JUPITER:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("found JUPITER\n");
                    break;
                }
            case Planet.planet.PLUTO:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("found PLUTO\n");
                    break;
                }
            }

            // these will use implicit value
            Console.WriteLine("\ntest comparison checks\n");
            if (EARTH == EARTH)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\npassed - EARTH == EARTH\n");
            }

            if (MERCURY < EARTH)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("passed - MERCURY < EARTH\n");
            }

            if (PLUTO > EARTH)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("passed - PLUTO > EARTH\n");
            }

            // test enum extension

            Console.WriteLine("\nbonus - enum extension\n");
            Console.WriteLine("PLUTO AsShort| " + Planet.planet.PLUTO.Value() + "  (9th planet)");


            // test ValueOf failure
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nValueOf that fails\n");
            try
            {
                planet = Planet.ValueOf("xxx");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone who wants to provide added features to enum's and maybe this will help someone convert their program from Java to C#

Answer (score 0):

In c#, you do this with classes, not enums. Create a base class with the virtual method you want to override.

Each member of the Java enum will be a sub-class with the implementation you want.

Finally, create a read-only static field in the base class for each enum member, initializing it with an instance of the sub-class for that enum value.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the [answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9086613/4226080) I found a slightly other approach that even allows you individual behavior / data with an enum similar structure. It is maybe not a real answer to the question, because it does not fulfill:

> Edit :: To clarify, I do not want to provide concrete classes for each specific bit of logic. IE, creating an interface acceptPlayer and creating many new classes is not appropiate

The following construct together with C# 7 gives a very enum like syntax:

```
public abstract class Logic
{
    private Logic() { }

    public abstract void acceptPlayer(Player player);

    public sealed class PayDay : Logic
    {
        public PayDay(DateTime timeOfPayment)
        {
            TimeOfPayment = timeOfPayment;
        }

        public DateTime TimeOfPayment { get; }

        public override void acceptPlayer(Player player)
        {
            // Perform logic
        }
    }

    public sealed class CollectCash : Logic
    {
        public CollectCash(int amountOfMoney)
        {
            AmountOfMoney = amountOfMoney;
        }

        public int AmountOfMoney { get; }

        public override void acceptPlayer(Player player)
        {
            // Perform logic
        }
    }

    public sealed class EtcEtc : Logic
    {
        public override void acceptPlayer(Player player)
        {
            // Perform logic
        }
    };
}
```

The private constructor of the abstract Logic class and the sealed implementations guarantee that there is only a well defined set of options that are all part of the scope of the Logic class.

Creation looks somewhat unusual:

```
Logic logic = new Logic.PayDay(DateTime.Now);
```

But together with C# 7's Pattern Matching it even starts to feel like an enum:

```
switch (logic)
{
    case Logic.PayDay payday:
        var timeOfPayment = payday.TimeOfPayment;
        // ...
        break;
    case Logic.CollectCash collectCash:
        // ...
        break;
    // ...
}
```

And also other test logic is quite readable:

```
if (logic is Logic.EtcEtc)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or if you need the casted instance:

```
if (logic is Logic.EtcEtc etcEtc)
{
    // ...
}
```