# java enums vs C# enums - missing features

Tags: c#, java, enums

in java I could easily describe an enum with aditional data.
I could describe it something like this

```
public enum OperatorType
{
    GreaterOrEqual  (">=", "GreaterOrEqual"),
    Greater         (">" ,"Greater"),
    Less            ("<", "Less"),
    LessOrEqual     ("<=", "LessOrEqual"),
    Equal           ("==", "Equal"),
    Between         ("Between", "Between"),
    Around          ("Around","Around");

    private final String symbol;
    private final String name;

    private OperatorType(final String symbol, final String name) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And then add a static method that iterates over values(), adds all data to a hashmap and allow to retrieve from the map full enum data by one of its attriburtes as a key.

In brief, enum is a very developed type in java.

Now,
moving to c#, what are my options?
I want to hold an enum with its attributes, load it to a map, and retreive by key when I need. Do I have anything to assist (like, a singletone for each enum - which is not a good idea).
Thanks.

Comment: C# doesn't support anything like this.  Sorry.

Comment: java is quite a black sheep. You could do some data container and just use the enums as keys.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks. so what are the popular solutions to handle enum data?

Comment: @Toni: Black sheep? this feature is awsome.

Comment: But for your specific use case you don't need to have that kind of stuff in your enum. Just provide a static method in a (helper) class, e.g. `PopulateOperatorMapping`, in which you fill a dictionary with an enum-to-string-tuple mapping and you should be fine.

Comment: The big advantage of the Java-style enum is that they are type safe: the compiler enforces that any valid instance of the type is always one of the enumerated values.  In C# on the other hand, enums are really just a small amount of syntactic sugar on top of a plain `int`.

Comment: `PopulateOperatorMapping` is less OOP

Comment: Also see [is-it-possible-to-mimic-this-java-enum-code-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086552/is-it-possible-to-mimic-this-java-enum-code-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 9):

I would just create a class with `public static readonly` instances of each type and ditch enums altogether.  You can use them as dictionary keys or do whatever you like. If you still intend to map them to an underlying data type (`int`) then you can create implicit operators for that too.

```
public class OperatorType
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, OperatorType> OperatorMapping = new Dictionary<int, OperatorType>();

    public static readonly OperatorType GreaterOrEqual  = new OperatorType(0, ">=", "GreaterOrEqual");
    public static readonly OperatorType Greater         = new OperatorType(1, ">", "Greater");



    public readonly String symbol;
    public readonly String name;
    private readonly int underlyingValue;

    private OperatorType(int underlyingValue, string symbol, string name) {
        this.underlyingValue = underlyingValue;
        OperatorMapping[underlyingValue] = this;

        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(OperatorType operatorType)
    {
        return operatorType.underlyingValue;
    }

    public static implicit operator OperatorType(int value)
    {
        return OperatorMapping[value];
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Dictionary<OperatorType, string> operators = new Dictionary<OperatorType, string>();

operators.Add(OperatorType.GreaterOrEqual, "Greater or equal");

Console.WriteLine(operators[OperatorType.GreaterOrEqual]); //"Greater or equal"

OperatorType operatorType = 1;

Console.WriteLine(operatorType.name); //"Greater"
```

If you don't care about an underlying value, don't include it. Also consider whether or not the `Dictionary` mapping should be threadsafe for your usage. You can also expose a static `IEnumerable<OperatorType>` (or other collection) to get all operators defined if you want.

EDIT: On second thought, `explicit` operators are possibly preferable instead of `implicit`, both to conform with typical .NET best practices and to better match typical `enum` conversions.

Comment: Nice solution, but how does this work when comparing these values? Normally you could just check `object.OperatorType == OperatorType.Equal`, but I don't think that will work in this case since you're working with objects instead of enums. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Sander: It will still work fine as it will use object reference equality and (in theory) each operator exists as a singleton. If for a particular usage that's not the case, then you can implement `IEquatable<OperatorType>` and override `Object.Equals` and the equality `==` operator to check the underlying integer value.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Is it true that each operator acts as a singleton? I somehow assumed that each call to `OperatorType.Type` would create a new instance of `OperatorType`.

Comment: @Sander: Nope, in this case they're declared as `static readonly` _fields_. This means that they're assigned once when the type is first accessed (either as a field initializer as I have it written in my answer, or in the static constructor) and persist for the lifetime of the application. By making the instance constructor private, that means users of `OperatorType` can _only_ use/reference/access the initial set of operators exposed.

Comment: @Sander: Oh, and perhaps another tidbit is that it's defined as a _reference-type_ `class` rather than a value-type `struct`. This means passing the operators around passes references to them and doesn't make value-type copies.

Answer (score 4):

The most convinient workaround might be to create an extension method to your enum type, and return the associated symbols.

Something like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            tester t = tester.x;
            t.testenums();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }

    public static class ext
    {
        public static void testenums(this tester x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
        }
    }

    public enum tester
    {
        x,
        y
    }
}
```

Of course you can write a more complex extension method, with return value, etc, this is just an example how to do it.

Comment: This, combined with [`public static readonly`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13445318/712526) instances (to be returned by the extension method) is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't really have the same feature. However there are several possibilities to get really close (and potentially more flexible as well).

Sticking to regular enums, you could use attributes to enrich with extra information. Of course, this requires reflection to work with that

```
public enum OperatorType
{
    [DisplayName(">=")]
    GreaterOrEqual,
    // ...
}
```

There are several patterns to work with this, e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28087/DisplayNameAttribute-for-Enumerations, google for more.

Another approach can be to enhance your enumeration types using regular classes:

```
public class OperatorType
{
   public static OperatorType GreaterOrEqual = new OperatorType(">=", "GreaterOrEqual");
   // ...

   string symbol;
   string name;
   private OperatorType(string symbol, string name)
   {
       this.symbol = symbol;
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

[This article](http://www.devx.com/enterprise/Article/28246) describes some other ways to work with enum-like types in C#

Answer (score 2):

You can create an attribute:

```
public class EnumKeyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public EnumKeyAttribute(string key, string description)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Description = description;
    }
}
```

Then apply it to your enum

```
public enum OperatorType
{
    [EnumKey(">=", "GreaterOrEqual")]
    GreaterOrEqual,

    [EnumKey(">", "Greater")]
    Greater,

    [EnumKey("<", "Less")]
    Less,

    [EnumKey("<=", "LessOrEqual")]
    LessOrEqual,

    [EnumKey("==", "Equal")]
    Equal,

    [EnumKey("Between", "Between")]
    Between,

    [EnumKey("Around", "Around")]
    Around
}
```

To get the attribute data you can use reflection.  Below is an example of getting the attribute for "Less"

```
        MemberInfo memberInfo = typeof(OperatorType).GetMember(OperatorType.Less.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

        if(memberInfo != null)
        {
            EnumKeyAttribute attribute = (EnumKeyAttribute)memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumKeyAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine(attribute.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(attribute.Description);
        }
```

But because these enums are not created at runtime you can increase your efficiency by creating a static method that looks up the value in a dictionary.  Do this as an extension method for ease of use

```
public static class KeyFinder
{
    private static Dictionary<OperatorType, EnumKeyAttribute> lookupTable =
        new Dictionary<OperatorType, EnumKeyAttribute>();

    public static EnumKeyAttribute GetKey(this OperatorType type)
    {

        if (lookupTable.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            return lookupTable[type];
        }

        MemberInfo memberInfo = typeof(OperatorType).GetMember(type.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

        if (memberInfo != null)
        {
            EnumKeyAttribute attribute = (EnumKeyAttribute)memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumKeyAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();

            if (attribute != null)
            {
                lookupTable.Add(type, attribute);
                return attribute;
            }
        }

        // add a null value so next time it doesn't use reflection only to find nothing
        lookupTable.Add(type, null);

        return null;
    }
}
```

So now to get the values you simply do the following:

```
OperatorType.Less.GetKey().Key
OperatorType.Less.GetKey().Description
```

Just be careful of null reference exceptions (since it will return null if it can't find an attribute).  If you want to find by key you can simply create other extension methods that use the string value as the key.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the functionality of Java-style enums in C#, I see three reasonable ways to implement it:

1. Use a C# enum and a static class of helper methods.  You lose type safety, but this is an otherwise very workable solution.
2. Use a C# enum and a set of extension methods.  Probably the most idiomatic C# solution, but you still have to deal with the loss of type safety (your extension methods should be able to cope with out-of-range values, even if only by throwing an exception).
3. Use the [type-safe enum pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092015/advantages-of-javas-enum-over-the-old-typesafe-enum-pattern) that was common in Java before the language gained the `enum` keyword in Java 5.  If you have non-trivial logic for each enum value, this would be my preference.