# Exposing enum type defined in a base library

Tags: c#, interface, enums

I am trying to revise my logging library. Here is where I'm stuck. I use an enumeration, let's call it ActionType, to identify my operations like UserLogin, PurchaseOrder... hundreds of them. And I use this type in my logger methods. But since I am seperating my logger library from my project specific code in the sake of loose coupling and base library can't access ActionType defined in a project, how can I achieve this. To clarify it let me explain same case in java. Java allows enums to implement interfaces. So I could write:

In base logger library I could define;

`public interface IActionType {}`

and in one of my several projects

`public enum ActionType implements IActionType {UserLogin, PurchaseOrder, .....}`

So when I called my  `logger.log(ActionType.UserLogin, ....)` base library would get the underlying action. This would all be suffice. Is there anyway around it to accomplish this in c#? By the way, I considered using IoC containers, but I want something more elegant.

Many thanks for any help...

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to mimic this java enum code in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086552/is-it-possible-to-mimic-this-java-enum-code-in-c-sharp). In short, C# enums are much simpler than Java enums, so you probably need to switch to a fixed number of static instances (a.k.a. old Java enum style).

Comment: So, you want both your logger and base library to reference the shared enumeration, but not reference each other? It that an accurate description of the problem?

Comment: Yes. Indeed, I want to define the enum in my base library, and try to fill it project specfic in many different projects. That's why I gave java example.

Comment: Did you consider a "core" project that your logger and base library can share - this can contain the enumeration and both the logger and base library can reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is approach log4net uses for `Level` class (yes, it is class, not enum):

```
public class ActionType : IActionType
{
   public static readonly ActionType UserLogin;
   public static readonly ActionType PurchaseOrder;

   static ActionType()
   {
       UserLogin = new ActionType(1, "User Login");
       // ...
   }

   public ActionType(int value, string name)
   {           
       // verify arguments values
       Value = value;
       Name = name;
   }

   public int Value { get; private set; }
   public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

And interface

```
public interface IActionType
{
    int Value { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Usage:

```
logger.Log(ActionType.UserLogin);
```

Comment: Details: There's a word `class` too much in the instance constructor. Then the static constructor needs parenthesis.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much. This will solve my problem very well. Secondly, I'm curious if this would cause any performance problem since I will be defining maybe 1000 classes for each of my 1000 actions? I think 1000 isn't that much, is it?

Comment: @dopache well, those objects will be created only once, and it will take about 4Kb of memory (if only Value property will be used)

Answer (score 3):

Lazy beat me to it but I'll post my solution anyway

```
public void MyUsage(ITypesafeEnum myEnum)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myEnum.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(myEnum.Val);
}

public interface ITypesafeEnum{
    string Name{get;}
    int Val {get;}
}

public  class TypesafeEnum:ITypesafeEnum{

    public string Name {get;private set;}
    public int Val {get;private set;}
    private TypesafeEnum(){}
    private TypesafeEnum(string name, int val){
        Name = name;
        Val = val;
    }

    public static readonly TypesafeEnum Bedroom = new TypesafeEnum("Bedroom", 1);
    public static readonly TypesafeEnum LivingRoom = new TypesafeEnum("Living Room",2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks four your attention :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that uses generics:

```
public void Log<EnumType>(EnumType enumMember)
{
    var name = enumMember.ToString();
    int value = (int)(object)enumMember;
    Console.WriteLine(name + " = " + value);
}
```

Calling the above method like this:

```
Log<ActionType>(ActionType.UserLogin);
Log<ActionType>(ActionType.PurchaseOrder);
```

Results in an output like the following:

```
UserLogin = 0
PurchaseOrder = 1
```