# porting specific Java Enums and Classes to C#

Tags: java, c#, enums, super

I know there are som posts about this, but i couldnt find any post that fits specificly to my problem.

I started to recreate an old flash game in Java, then i switched to unity.

Now i am stuck with porting my Classes, that contain java enums to C#

For example i have the following classes:

Item

Weapon (extends Item)

Sword  (extends Weapon) Sword contains enum Type

```
    enum Type{
        //Name           min max price 2hand   baselvl  ranged
        Falchion        ( 1,  4,  324, false, (byte)  1, false),
        Shortsword      ( 1,  5,  346, false, (byte)  1, false),
        Cutlass         ( 2,  6,  411, false, (byte)  3, false),
        Throwingknife   ( 2,  9,  478, false, (byte)  3,  true), //RANGED
        Longsword       ( 2,  8,  567,  true, (byte)  5, false), //TWOHANDED
        Broadsword      ( 4,  8,  690, false, (byte)  7, false),
        Katana          ( 4, 11,  807,  true, (byte)  9, false), //TWOHANDED
        Saber           ( 7, 12, 1210, false, (byte) 10, false),
        Flamberge       ( 8, 17, 1623,  true, (byte) 13, false), //TWOHANDED
        Lightsaber      (12, 20, 2732, false, (byte) 15, false);

        final int minDMG;   
        final int maxDMG;
        final int price;
        final byte baseLVL;
        final boolean twoHanded;
        final boolean ranged;

        private Type(int minD, int maxD, int p, boolean twoHa, byte bLVL, boolean r) {
            this.minDMG = minD;
            this.maxDMG = maxD;
            this.price = p;
            this.twoHanded = twoHa;
            this.baseLVL = bLVL;
            this.ranged = r;
        }

        public static final Type[] types = Type.values();
        public static Type getType(int i) {
            return Type.types[i];   
        }
     }
```

for the Constructor of Sword I use:

```
    public Sword(int Index) {

        super("Sword",2,""+types[Index], types[Index].minDMG,types[Index].maxDMG,types[Index].price,types[Index].twoHanded,types[Index].baseLVL,types[Index].ranged);   
    }
```

Weapon:

```
    public Weapon(String wCl, int wCID, String n,int minD, int maxD, int p, boolean twoHa, byte bLVL, boolean r) {
        super("Weapon",n,minD,maxD,p,twoHa, bLVL,r);
        this.weaponClass        = wCl;
        this.weaponClassID  = wCID;     
    }
```

And finally Item:

```
public Item(String iC, String n,int minD, int maxD, int p, boolean twoHa, byte bLVL,boolean r) {
        //Weapon
        this.condition = initCondition();
        this.name           = n;
        this.minDMG         = minD  * this.condition.multiplier + ((this.condition.multiplier - 1) * 1);
        this.maxDMG         = maxD  * this.condition.multiplier + ((this.condition.multiplier - 1) * 1);
        this.price          = p     * this.condition.multiplier*13;
        this.twohanded      = twoHa;
        this.bodypart       = "Hands";
        this.ranged = r;
}
```

to initialize it i can just write

```
Item i = new Sword(0);
```

I couldnt find a good solution in C#

my first solution that i used for the Condition enum in the Item class was creating a new c# class "Condition"

```
public class Condition
{
    readonly string name;
    readonly int multiplier;
    readonly string color = "GREY";

    public Condition(string n, int m, string c) {
        this.name = n;
        this.multiplier = m;
        this.color = c;
    }
```

and then building a method for selecting and initializing said Condition inside the Item class

```
    public Condition condition;

    public Item(int _luck)
    {
        this.condition = generateCondition(conditionSelector(_luck));
    }
private Condition generateCondition(int selector)
    {
        if      (selector ==  0)                   return new Condition("Godlike"   , 15, "YELLOW"   ); //  0        -->  1%    MAX LVL LUCK Percentage:  0      -->  2%
        else if (selector >=  1 && selector <=  2) return new Condition("Legendary" , 10, "WHITE"    ); //  1 -   2  -->  2%    MAX LVL LUCK Percentage:  1 -  2 -->  4%
        else if (selector >=  3 && selector <=  5) return new Condition("Mythical"  ,  8, "PURPLE"   ); //  3 -   5  -->  3%    MAX LVL LUCK Percentage:  3 -  5 -->  6%
        else if (selector >=  6 && selector <=  9) return new Condition("Ultra Rare",  5, "DARKBLUE" ); //  6 -    9 -->  4%    MAX LVL LUCK Percentage:  6 -  9 -->  8%
        else if (selector >= 10 && selector <= 14) return new Condition("Rare"      ,  3, "LIGHTBLUE"); //  10 -  14 -->  5%    MAX LVL LUCK Percentage: 10 - 14 --> 10%
        else if (selector >= 15 && selector <= 20) return new Condition("Uncommon"  ,  2, "GREEN"    ); //  15 -  20 -->  6%    MAX LVL LUCK Percentage: 15 - 20 --> 12%
        else if (selector >= 15 && selector <= 20) return new Condition("Common"    ,  1, "GREY"     ); //  21 -  99 --> 79%    MAX LVL LUCK Percentage: 21 - 49 --> 58%

        return new Condition("Common", 1, "GREY");
    }
```

This works fine for the condition part of the item.

but I did not find a good way to port the other classes to C#

and I don't know how I can use the `super` equivalent `base` so that it fits my project

If you have posts that can help me more with my project you can link it below

*Note: this is a private project and not related to any homework or studyrelated stuff*

Answer (score 0):

You can call Parent's constructor in Child's constructor using below code.

```
public Sword(int index):base(index)
```

If you want modify the index and send something else then you can call a function which does the job in the constructor.

```
public Sword(int index):base(somefunction(index))
```

In your case, you need to send all together new set of parameters using "index" variable.

```
public Sword(int Index):base("Sword",2,""+types[Index], types[Index].minDMG,types[Index].maxDMG,types[Index].price,types[Index].twoHanded,types[Index].baseLVL,types[Index].ranged)
```

Comment: but where do i create the types array in C# ? 

do i need to create the classes

Sword
SwordManager

then create an SwordManager Array inside the Sword class.

to then fill in the Values for the name, dmg, etc. ?

Comment: In Java, where did u create the type array?

Comment: `        public static final Type[] types = Type.values();
        public static Type getType(int i) {
            return Type.types[i];   
        }
`

First code snippet

Comment: i assume types is a global variable. You can do the same in c# too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but, I wanted to match the Java enum in C# as much as possible.  If you check out this post, I believe that this comes close [Java Like enum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54961746/4408877) and I think you can use this to port your code from Java to C#